# How to underline individual items in a CListCtrl

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

We want some items in a CListView to appear like hypertext links.

I can make everything underlined by setting the lfUnderline flag in LOGFONT, and creating a font from this, before calling SetFont - but this applies to the whole CListView.

Does anyone know how to make individual items in a CListView to appear underlined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the custom-draw notifications and modifying the font on the particular item you want within the custom-draw handler.

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761817(VS.85).aspx) for details.

Comment: This is what I've done. I modified the font and set the underlined flag and changed the colour.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
oMyCListView.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_ONECLICKACTIVATE)
```

Comment: This won't work; it will set that style for the whole control rather than individual items as the OP asked for.